# How to use the ecclesiastic variant of latin with babel having more than one language?

Tags: babel, variant

I'm using `babel` in the following way:

```
\usepackage[main=portuges,latin]{babel}
```

How can I declare the latin ecclesiatic variant/style in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [`babel` documentation](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) and the [extension for Latin](http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/latin/latin.pdf). The code you have to type is:

```
\usepackage[main=portuguese,latin.ecclesiastic]{babel}
```

Comment: Thank you. I read the [```babel-latin``` documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/latin/latin.pdf) where this is not documented.